# Spring Security Virtual Threads and ThreadLocal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, virtual-threads

As I was reading up about virtual threads and their pitfalls I found this mention :

> Don't Cache Expensive Reusable Objects in Thread-Local Variables

> Virtual threads support thread-local variables just as platform
> threads do. See Thread-Local Variables for more information. Usually,
> thread-local variables are used to associate some context-specific
> information with the currently running code, such as the current
> transaction and user ID. This use of thread-local variables is
> perfectly reasonable with virtual threads. However, consider using the
> safer and more efficient scoped values. See Scoped Values for more
> information.

Here : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-68216B85-7B43-423E-91BA-11489B1ACA61

But i also remembered that Spring Security uses ThreadLocal to save the SecurityContext of a given request:

> By default, SecurityContextHolder uses a ThreadLocal to store these
> details, which means that the SecurityContext is always available to
> methods in the same thread, even if the SecurityContext is not
> explicitly passed around as an argument to those methods. Using a
> ThreadLocal in this way is quite safe if you take care to clear the
> thread after the present principal’s request is processed. Spring
> Security’s FilterChainProxy ensures that the SecurityContext is always
> cleared.

Docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html

So the question is : is it safe to use virtual threads in a Spring Boot REST Application with endpoints that do require authentication and authorization and therefor have a `SecurityContext` ? Is this considered a pitfall ?

Thanks !

Comment: No, not considered a security flaw, just does not use the advantages of scoped values. Although scoped values are preferable for virtual threads, a thread can be "tagged" with `SecurityContext` (as with any other traditionally TL-based context)  _at any time_, while `ScopedValue`s have to be defined _at the time of thread initiation_. This entices a lot of refactoring of ideology which is based on thread pools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible 1) to implement a custom `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` which retrieves `SecurityContext` from a `ScopedValue` and saves it there:

```
public class ScopedSecurityContextHolderStrategy implements SecurityContextHolderStrategy {
    private static final ScopedValue<SecurityContextScopedValueHolder> SECURITY_CONTEXT = ScopedValue.newInstance();

    private static class SecurityContextScopedValueHolder {
        
        private SecurityContext securityContext;

        public SecurityContext getSecurityContext() {
            return securityContext;
        }

        public void setSecurityContext(SecurityContext securityContext) {
            this.securityContext = securityContext;
        }

    }
    
    @Override
    public void clearContext() {
        retrieveSecurityContextScopedValueHolder().setSecurityContext(null);
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityContext getContext() {
        return retrieveSecurityContextScopedValueHolder().getSecurityContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContext(SecurityContext context) {
        retrieveSecurityContextScopedValueHolder().setSecurityContext(context);
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityContext createEmptyContext() {
        return new SecurityContextImpl();
    }
    
    private SecurityContextScopedValueHolder retrieveSecurityContextScopedValueHolder() {
        if (SECURITY_CONTEXT.isBound()) {
            return SECURITY_CONTEXT.get();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Security Context Scoped Value not bound");
        }
    }
    
    public static ScopedValue.Carrier getSecuriyContextCarrier() {
        return ScopedValue.where(SECURITY_CONTEXT, new SecurityContextScopedValueHolder());
    }

}
```

and 2) configure Tomcat to start a virtual thread with the `ScopedValue`, bound to it:

```
@Component
public class TomcatVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer 
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    private static class ScopedVirtualThreadExecutor extends VirtualThreadExecutor {

        public ScopedVirtualThreadExecutor(String namePrefix) {
            super(namePrefix);
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            super.execute(() -> ScopedSecurityContextHolderStrategy.getSecuriyContextCarrier().run(command));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addProtocolHandlerCustomizers((protocolHandler) -> protocolHandler
                .setExecutor(new ScopedVirtualThreadExecutor("tomcat-handler-")));
    }

}
```

it is easy to see, however, a substantial awkwardness in such approach.

First, the approach is tightly bound to type of web server/servlet container, Tomcat in our case. The solution for other servers, like Undertow or Jetty, might be different if at all possible.

Second, Spring Security is a ubiquitous thing that `SecurityContext` is meant to be used everywhere, not only on server's worker threads. For example, there might be a need to setup a `SecurityContext` on a cron/scheduler thread or just on a thread, managed by a standalone `Executor`. `ScopeValue`-based approach will require similar binding of it to such thread, while with a standard `ThreadLocal`-bound `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` the context can be set without any thread tweaking.

All in all, this technique introduces some not-very-welcome coupling between the code which creates a thread and the code which sets/retrieves `SecurityContext`.

From conceptual standpoint, I'd daresay that the concepts of Structured Programming and Spring Security don't get along with each other very well - at least in current versions of both.

The small POC Spring Boot project is available [here](https://github.com/eager-zh/spring-security-scoped-value).

Note that the example works for Spring Boot 3.2.2, its applicability to earlier and later versions is not guaranteed as things with Loom are rather volatile at the moment.

---